# How to import historical data (CSV) from Yahoo Finance in SpreadSheets

Tags: csv, google-sheets, web-scraping, google-sheets-formula, yahoo-finance

I try to import historical data (CSV) for APPLE. I use ImportData function in Google Sheet with

https://query1.finance.yahoo.com/v7/finance/download/AAPL?period1=1577982443&period2=1609604843&interval=1d&events=history&includeAdjustedClose=true

but the result is "#N/A".

I want to get the CSV because there is 3 decimals. And only 2, on the website.

```
=IMPORTXML("https://query1.finance.yahoo.com/v7/finance/download/AAPL?period1=1577982443&period2=1609604843&interval=1d&events=history&includeAdjustedClose=true")
```

There is a script after to obtain the file : AAPL.csv .

Can you help me ?

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, in the case of the URL, it seems that `IMPORTDATA` and `IMPORTXML` cannot be used. But, fortunately, I confirmed that `UrlFetchApp` of Google Apps Script can be retrieved the CSV data. So, in this answer, I would like to propose to use Google Apps Script for achieving your goal.

#### Sample script:

Please copy and paste the following script to the script editor of Google Spreadsheet, and please put `=SAMPLE("https://query1.finance.yahoo.com/v7/finance/download/AAPL?period1=1577982443&period2=1609604843&interval=1d&events=history&includeAdjustedClose=true")` to a cell. This script is used as the custom function. By this, the CSV data can be retrieved in the cells.

```
const SAMPLE = url => Utilities.parseCsv(UrlFetchApp.fetch(url).getContentText());
```

#### Result:

When above script is used, the following result is obtained.

[image]

#### References:

- [Custom Functions in Google Sheets](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/functions)
- [Class UrlFetchApp](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app)
- [Utilities.parseCsv()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/utilities/utilities#parsecsvcsv)

Comment: @Stratagenus also note that you won't be able to use that URL with [IMPORTXML](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093342?hl=en) because that URL will download the data (it probably runs a request script that returns the downloaded data) and therefore the URL does not contain any XML, HTML, CSV, TSV or RSS feed.