# How to Import Historical Data from Yahoo Finance into Google Sheets and make it Auto-Update?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, triggers, scheduled-tasks, yahoo-finance

I've been trying to get Yahoo Finance ES symbol daily OHLC data into Google Sheet.

I've checked the disabling javascript and reloading the page method by [@Rubén](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/115665/219739) and the OHLC data displays after reloading the page. But the IMPORT formulas returns `#N/A Resource at URL Not Found`.

I also tried [@user0](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/126329/219739) methods (save the IMPORTJSON one) [here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1u_lM3hZeq2ZlV8PPTKEqFuWp_bchdXyQBDdhZQFHbGU/edit#gid=1619515893) but no luck there too.

Then I've tested the script by [@JohnA](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67080713/10789707) and it does retrieve the data.

Here's [@JohnA Script output](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1u_lM3hZeq2ZlV8PPTKEqFuWp_bchdXyQBDdhZQFHbGU/edit#gid=357604388) I got.

But now I'm wondering how to make it auto-update at least every day (it is daily data).

I'm not sure how to proceed since [@JohnA's Script](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67080713/10789707) involves handling a `CSV` file.

I've enabled `calculation on change and every minute` as detailed here: [How to Configure Auto Refresh for Googlesheets](http://help.cryptosheets.com/en/articles/4456485-how-to-configure-auto-refresh-for-googlesheets)

Is there any workaround allowing to just get the data into Google Sheet without needing the csv step?

Or is it possible to still pull the data from the `CSV` while getting Google sheet to auto-update daily? If yes, how to do it?

Thanks for any advice, always very much appreciated!

The [test Sheet1 and Sheet2](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1u_lM3hZeq2ZlV8PPTKEqFuWp_bchdXyQBDdhZQFHbGU/edit?usp=sharing)

Related scripts by [@Tanaike 1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65545878/10789707) [@Tanaike 2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66609503/10789707)

Comment: I am glad you found my answer helpful. Google sheets has Triggers, you can set it to fire off daily during a specified hour range.

Comment: JohnA's script works for me.  If you can't get that to work something's wrong or there's something your not telling us

Comment: JohnA's script copies it directly into a sheet

Comment: Thanks a lot @John a for the Trigger advice. I thought the recalculation method was the one.

Comment: @Cooper yes it is working. But my question was about getting it update daily. Either with csv method or with another method. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In script editor look for the clock

[image]

Then complete the form

[image]

Optionally, you can set a trigger via a script

```
/**
 * Creates time-driven triggers
 *
 * https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/script/clock-trigger-builder
 */
function createTimeDrivenTriggers() {
  // Trigger every day at 04:00AM CT.
  ScriptApp.newTrigger('csvDaily')
      .timeBased()
      .everyDays(1)
      .atHour(4)
      .create();
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the details and very nice scripts! Much value. I got it set. Will see if it updates and be back by tomorrow. Thanks again for the great help! Be well!

Comment: I added new instruments today and run the script. Yesterday's data came up for the instruments added yesterday.  It must be due to the url's fixed period numbers: https://query1.finance.yahoo.com/v7/finance/download/ES=F?period1=`1618358400`&period2=`1618444800`&interval=1d&events=history&includeAdjustedClose=true

Comment: I found out that you can get the current day's data csv file only by shortening the url this way:
https://query1.finance.yahoo.com/v7/finance/download/EURUSD=X?interval=1d
or that way:
https://query1.finance.yahoo.com/v7/finance/download/EURUSD=X?events=history

Comment: I could not get it to return the complete csv without at least the `period2` included in the csv:
That works:
https://query1.finance.yahoo.com/v7/finance/download/EURUSD=X?period2=1618589352&interval=1d&events=history&includeAdjustedClose=true
But that doesn't:
https://query1.finance.yahoo.com/v7/finance/download/EURUSD=X?period1=1587053352&interval=1d&events=history&includeAdjustedClose=true
Tricky figuring out the numbering scheme YF uses for the periods... Any insights? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Else it would require automating the addition of the daily new data figures to stack the Google sheet output. Any other suggestion? Thanks a lot again.

Comment: Yahoo uses Unix timestamps. https://www.unixtimestamp.com

Assume G10 has the date the formula is =(G10-DATE(1970,1,1))*86400

Comment: I built a model to do some backtesting on stocks, if you invested x dollars in a stock what would the value be today. I built it just for fun, I am still vetting the results. One example shows if you bought 100 shares of AAPL at $22 when their IPO kicked off in 1980, one would have over $3M today. https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1qbLOjTdzISICTKyUp_jK6gZbQCt-OwtDYYy3HNJygeE/edit#gid=141819050

Comment: Good exercise thanks a lot! I've found this `investor.gov` compound-interest-calculator:
`https://www.investor.gov/financial-tools-calculators/calculators/compound-interest-calculator`
Have fun!

Comment: Also, I added 8 sheets to the test Spreadsheet from the other day:
`https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1u_lM3hZeq2ZlV8PPTKEqFuWp_bchdXyQBDdhZQFHbGU/edit#gid=1208119405`
Now you can select which ticker symbol from all Yahoo Finance list (from up to 2017). Found the list here: `https://investexcel.net/all-yahoo-finance-stock-tickers/` and archived `https://archive.org/details/yahoo-ticker-symbols-september-2017`

Comment: I have it set so that cells `E14` to `E17` output the custom URLs for 1 year | 1 month | 1 week | 1day back from running day.

I'm trying to figure out (I forgot how to do it) how to adapt your script so that we can input cells `E14` | `E15` | `E16` | `E17` (from the DATA_PICKER sheet) to basically make it auto update from there.
Any insights on how to adapt the `var csvUrl = E14`: instead of the yahoo direct url?
Thanks a lot!

Comment: Compound calculator Output:
https://i.imgur.com/VxsC1wl.png

Comment: I may be missing something, but it is easy to grab values from a sheet, I prefer to use Named Ranges though, this way if your sheet addresses change you do not have to change the script.
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var symbol = ss.getRange(Data_Picker!E14).getValue();
or assuming you named E14 OneYearURL 
var symbol = ss.getRange("OneYearURL").getValue();

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/231251/discussion-between-johna-and-lod).